# SQL Server : update query doesn't change anything, shows no error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the table with the values from the same table.

What I want is to change the connection setup in the rows where the worker and client are same and that the changed row Connection setup started in 5mins after the other connection (with the same worker and client) ended.

I first created a `SELECT` query that returned me all the rows that needed to be changed

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1
              WHERE worker = t.worker 
                AND client = t.client
                AND t.SessionNo != SessionNo
                AND t.[Connection setup] <= DATEADD(mi, 5, [Connection end])
                AND t.[Connection setup] >= [Connection end])
```

Then I tried to import this query inside of an `UPDATE` query, but it didn't change anything :/ and it doesn't show me any errors.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Start = t2.Start
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON (t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo)
WHERE t.worker = t2.worker
  AND t.client = t2.client
  AND t2.SessionNo <> t.SessionNo
  AND t.[Connection setup] <= DATEADD(mi, 5, t2.[Connection end])
  AND t.[Connection setup] >= t2.[Connection end]
```

Example:

The first table are the rows that should be changed. As you can see there is a column "right time" that shows what value should they have after the update.

```
   SessionNo  worker    Tag       Start     Ende    Dauer   Connection setup    Connection end      client      right_time
1   424568  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 13:45   13:49   00:04   09.01.2020 13:45:00 09.01.2020 13:49:00 OBENAT1D0209    13:44
2   269650  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 10:25   10:47   00:21   09.03.2020 10:25:00 09.03.2020 10:47:00 OBENAT1D0117    10:24
3   280892  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 12:19   12:22   00:03   09.03.2020 12:19:00 09.03.2020 12:22:00 OBENAT1D0117    12:19
4   175250  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 13:12   13:13   00:01   09.03.2020 13:12:00 09.03.2020 13:13:00 ORTNERAT1D0001  13:04
5   332684  dg  09.05.2020 00:00:00 16:05   16:33   00:28   09.05.2020 16:05:00 09.05.2020 16:33:00 KILLYAT3D0102   15:57
```

but as you can see here `Start` column is still the same.

```
   SessionNo  worker    Tag       Start     Ende    Dauer   Connection setup    Connection end      client      right_time
1   317045  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 09:29   09:38   00:09   09.01.2020 09:29:00 09.01.2020 09:38:00 AUMAAT1D0124    09:29
2   144035  sb  09.01.2020 00:00:00 11:09   11:27   00:18   09.01.2020 11:09:00 09.01.2020 11:27:00 OBENAT1D0231    11:09
3   437704  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 13:44   13:44   00:00   09.01.2020 13:44:00 09.01.2020 13:44:00 OBENAT1D0209    13:44
4   424568  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 13:45   13:49   00:04   09.01.2020 13:45:00 09.01.2020 13:49:00 OBENAT1D0209    13:44
5   219640  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 15:16   15:26   00:10   09.01.2020 15:16:00 09.01.2020 15:26:00 OBENAT1D0209    15:16
6   201023  mh  09.01.2020 00:00:00 16:29   16:35   00:06   09.01.2020 16:29:00 09.01.2020 16:35:00 OBENAT1D0209    16:29
7   236114  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 08:55   09:08   00:12   09.03.2020 08:55:00 09.03.2020 09:08:00 NULL    NULL
8   271379  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 10:24   10:25   00:00   09.03.2020 10:24:00 09.03.2020 10:25:00 OBENAT1D0117    10:24
9   269650  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 10:25   10:47   00:21   09.03.2020 10:25:00 09.03.2020 10:47:00 OBENAT1D0117    10:24
10  290765  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 12:19   12:19   00:00   09.03.2020 12:19:00 09.03.2020 12:19:00 OBENAT1D0117    12:19
11  280892  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 12:19   12:22   00:03   09.03.2020 12:19:00 09.03.2020 12:22:00 OBENAT1D0117    12:19
12  538583  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 12:30   12:58   00:28   09.03.2020 12:30:00 09.03.2020 12:58:00 RATTAYAT1D0107  NULL
13  697202  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 13:04   13:08   00:04   09.03.2020 13:04:00 09.03.2020 13:08:00 ORTNERAT1D0001  13:04
14  175250  mg  09.03.2020 00:00:00 13:12   13:13   00:01   09.03.2020 13:12:00 09.03.2020 13:13:00 ORTNERAT1D0001  13:04
15  330580  dg  09.05.2020 00:00:00 15:57   16:05   00:08   09.05.2020 15:57:00 09.05.2020 16:05:00 KILLYAT3D0102   15:57
16  332684  dg  09.05.2020 00:00:00 16:05   16:33   00:28   09.05.2020 16:05:00 09.05.2020 16:33:00 KILLYAT3D0102   15:57
```

**NOTE** : In this case, in order to test the values I am changing the `Start` column instead of the connection startup.

Comment: I *assume*, therefore, that when you perform the `UPDATE` it shows no rows are effected as well in the output window. If so, then that's because your `JOIN` criteria isn't correct. The `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are the same, instead of writing it out as a `SELECT` with an `EXISTS`, write it out with a `JOIN` as well, ensure that returns data, and then change it to an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Also, in your `UPDATE` you have `ON (t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo)` **and** `t.SessionNo != t2.essionNo`. Howw can `t.SessionNo ` equal *and* not equal `t2.SessionNo`? It *can't*.

Comment: How should I join them then ? since there is no other unique values that can be used to join on. should I then use different kind of approach ? as in not use **JOIN** at all

Comment: The problem is that `t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo` directly conflicts with `t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo`; it's impossible for both those clauses for be true. if `t.SessionNo` equals `t2.SessionNo` is, by definition not *not* equal `t2.SessionNo`... (intentional double negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating zero rows, because of:

```
ON (t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo)
...
AND t2.SessionNo <> t.SessionNo
```

You want to find rows with another session number, but you have `t.SessionNo = t2.SessionNo`, so this is exactly what you *don't* want.

You seem to think that a join needs a comparision with `=` on a single column, but this is not true. A join condition can be any boolean expression.

This may work for you:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Start = t2.Start
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON  t.worker = t2.worker
                     AND t.client = t2.client
                     AND t.SessionNo <> t2.SessionNo
                     AND t.[Connection setup] <= DATEADD(mi, 5, t2.[Connection end])
                     AND t.[Connection setup] >= t2.[Connection end];
```

Comment: I did the query based on some findings online, didn't quite understood how it all should work exactly. Your answer does help, but I do have one problem. when there are multiple connections with the same client from the same worker and all connections happened in less than 5 min between them. How can I get that all those connections get the same Start ?(I added an example to my question)

Comment: @AmilaBečirović . . . This answers the question you originally asked.  I would suggest that you remove the edit from this question, accept this answer, and ask a *new* question.  Stack Overflow is not a game of "help me figure out my question".

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I was planning on accepting this answer, as you said it does answer the original question. I just wanted to ask if the person who wrote the answer has an idea how I could get this additional question done, since they are already familiar with my question as it is. People sometime do have additional questions, I didn't meant to be rude ....I just want to understand how it works not just copy/paste it

Comment: @miwa_p . . . I didn't mean for the comment to sound harsh, just a statement of fact.  There are modifications to a question that clarify the question being asked -- for instance, "I don't want to output the date with a time component".  However you added an entirely new condition, which makes it a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...you are right, it is a new question. but at the time I was writing it, I didn't think of it as a new topic, more like a small addition to original q. Since then I figured it is more complex than I thought and am still searching how to figure it out. thank you for clarifying it for me....will try to be more specific next time